# MVC Login use different field and prevent duplicates

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added a few fields (`Email`, `Forename`, `Surname`, etc) to the `AspNetUsers` table but I would like to know if it is possible to amend the login of the standard MVC template inside Visual Studio 2013 to use the new `Email` field instead.

I've altered everything as far as I can see, please see below.

**LoginViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountController**

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Email or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

For some unknown reason, despite the registration process saving the values in the correct fields, I cannot log on with a user using an email address, unless after the user is registered I open the AspNetUsers table and swap the Email and UserName data around.

Please, what am I missing?

Also is it possible to check for existing email addresses before registration to ensure no possible duplicates?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to “amend” the login of the standard MVC template inside VS 2013 to use your new email field.

And yes, it is possible to check for an existing email prior to saving your stuff into the database. That is called “validation”.

Validation is a lengthy subject and can occur on many levels within an application. The two most common places where validation occurs are on the UI level and the Business logic level.

For example, ensuring that a field (such as a password) is required usually occurs in the UI level. The most common practice is to use Attributes on your properties. These attributes are obtained via the DataAnnotations. Read up on those or google it. You’ll find a plethora of examples.

Another common way is to something called Fluent Validation but since you’re getting started, I strongly recommend using the DataAnnotations. As you get more experience and better understand what and how things are working, then gently move towards Fluent Validation if you see fit.

As for the Business logic level, this is where you (the programmer) usually put all the logic and rules related to your company. For example, consider this foolish example:
Company A may not care if duplicate emails are polluting his database. But Company B may care if duplicate emails are created therefore, the Business Logic between company A and company B will be very different and your code will reflect those differences.

In short, that is what we call Business Logic validation and usually, that occurs in another level within your application.

Unfortunately, I don’t have any code example to give you but you can find many examples online.

My advice is to start with a basic MVC step by step tutorial that’ll help you understand how everything works. I’m afraid answering (or showing you code) might end up raising more questions than answers.

Here’s what I’d do: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

From step 1 to step 11 which happens to covers validation and what not.

Hopes this helps (or not).